# Pyserial code hangs after a while

Tags: python, serial

I have some code that parses serial data into chunks for Kivy to read.

For some reason the code will work perfectly for a while and then stop. I think I need to clear the buffer/memory somewhere but I have no idea how to do this correctly.

The code looks for an STX (02 in HEX) and reads data until ETX (03).
Then it formats the data for Kivy to output to a display.

```
                while True:
                try:
                    buf = self.ser.read()
                    if buf.encode('hex') == '02':
                        data = '[02]'
                        while True:
                            tmp = self.ser.read()
                            if tmp.encode('hex') == '03':
                                data += '[03]'
                                break
                            else:
                                data += tmp
                        break
                    else:
                        print 'Finding STX... ', buf.encode('hex')
                except serial.SerialException as e:
                    print e
                    break

        if data.startswith('[02]'):
            data_header = data[4:6]
            data_list = ['00', '02']
            if data_header in data_list:
                content = data[7:-4]
                tmp = '[b][color=FFEC1F]' + content + '[/color][/b]'
                print "Updating content: ", data_header, tmp
                self.root.ids['lb_' + data_header].text = tmp
```

When I notice the display has stopped and SSH into it, I receive hundreds of lines of

> Updating content:  00 [b][color=FFEC1F]200[/color][/b]
>
> Updating content:  02 [b][color=FFEC1F]  383[/color][/b]
>
> Updating content:  00 [b][color=FFEC1F]199[/color][/b]
>
> Updating content:  02 [b][color=FFEC1F]  381[/color][/b]
>
> Updating content:  00 [b][color=FFEC1F]199[/color][/b]
>
> ..etc.

Until it catches up to the latest data.

Comment: I have noticed some funky things happening in the latest raspbian when the screen blanks out. I would suggest testing with the following:

Add `consoleblank=0` to the end of the first line of your `/boot/cmdline.txt`.  This will disable the screen sleep or whatever its actually called.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Though at the moment the screen doesn't appear to be sleeping. The Kivy app is still displayed but there is no data because the python script has hung/frozen.

Comment: ah ok, I must have misread the original post.